# How to change a long variable to a Timestamp in Java?

Tags: java, timestamp

How do I change a long variable to a Timestamp variable? I can convert it to a String but I need to convert it to Timestamp in order to use it in a database.

Comment: How does the value in the long correspond to the date?  You usually want it to make _some_ kind of sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Timestamp extends java.util.Date and it has a constructor that accepts a long.

Like this:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long inputLong = 1234567890l * 1000l;  // Constructor expects a milliseconds value

        Timestamp outputTimestamp = new Timestamp(inputLong);

        System.out.println (outputTimestamp);
    }

}
```

Comment: You are right: it extends Date and it has constructor that accepts long. But you are wrong with "i.e.". These 2 facts are independent. Inheritance does not dictate constructors.

Comment: @alexR Indeed, the javadoc says "A thin wrapper around java.util.Date" which is the correct wording.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Java, but an internet search suggests that `Timestamp` has a constructor which takes a `long`:

So, you can do something like this, perhaps:

```
Timestamp t = new Timestamp(l);
```

For more information, see http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Timestamp](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html). it has a constructor that receives long as the only parameter.