# How to change long variable to Timestamp in java?

Tags: java, timestamp

Do you know how to change a long variable to Timestamp variable ? I can convert it to a String but I need to convert it to Timestamp in order to use it in the database.

Comment: Asked and answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928650/how-to-change-a-long-variable-to-a-timestamp-in-java, voting to close this dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably something like (assuming millis is your long variable, and represents milliseconds):

```
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(millis)
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html

This question is better suited for stackoverflow though, I'm flagging it.